# Trait to see if a move constructor exists

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

How do ask the compiler if a type has a move constructor?

`std::is_move_constructible` doesn't apply because it will return `true` even if the type is copy constructible only.

Is there something that will return whether or not there is actually a user-defined move constructor?

EDIT:

For background, I am trying to create a type erased class that will (given a set of types) decide whether or not it is worth saving off a type erased version of the move constructor.

If at least one of these types does have an "interesting" move constructor (non trivial and actually implemented), then it should save off the move constructor, else it won't and will save space

```
#include <type_traits>

struct NoMove {
    NoMove(NoMove const&) {}
    //NoMove(NoMove&&) = delete;
};

struct InterestingMove {
    InterestingMove(InterestingMove&&) {}
};

template<typename T>
struct is_interesting_move_constructor :
    std::integral_constant<bool,
        std::is_move_constructible<T>::value &&
        !std::is_trivially_move_constructible<T>::value> {};

// Fails:
//static_assert(!is_interesting_move_constructor<NoMove>::value);

// Is fine:
static_assert(is_interesting_move_constructor<InterestingMove>::value);
```

The problem with this attempt is that it should return `false` on `NoMove` but it doesn't because `is_move_constructible` doesn't return true based on whether or not there is actually a move constructor

Type erased class sketch (think like a `std::any` but limited to a set of types):

```
template<typename... Ts> // One of these types will be held
struct type_eraser_thing
{
    void* obj; // pointer to actual thing
    std::function<void*(void*,void*)> move_constr;
    std::function<void*(void*,void const*)> copy_constr;
        // Plus other goodies not shown
    std::size_t size;

    template<typename T>
    type_eraser_thing(T const& other)
    {
        // static_assert to make sure T is in Ts...

        // Get the memory
        obj = malloc(sizeof(T));
        obj = new (obj) T(other);
        size = sizeof(T);

        // Save the move_constructor
        move_constr = [](void* dest, void* src){
            return new (dest) T(std::move(*reinterpret_cast<T*>(src)));
        };
    }
    // Other stuff (copy constructor, etc)
    //


    // The real problem the move constructor:
    type_eraser_thing(T&& other)
    {
        obj = malloc(other.size);
        obj = other.move_constr(obj,other.obj);
        obj.move_constr = other.move_constr;
        other.obj = nullptr;

    }
};
```

In the implementation of the move constructor, it doesn't make sense to have a call to a `std::function` (not really, but something similar) if the move constructor doesn't do anything, so I want to SFINAE it out if it doesn't do anything

Comment: Under what circumstances would you care whether the type is moved or copied? For many types - e.g. `int` - the two are indistinguishable. What's the ultimate goal of this exercise?

Comment: @Igor I am creating a type erasure utility......What I want to do is if at least one type from a collection of types has an "interesting" move constructor, then I will store a type erased lambda to that move constructor so that I can implement move assignment operator of this larger type erased type

Comment: @Igor But if none of this collection have an "interesting" move constructor, there is no point in storing it

Comment: So you want to check if the type is move-only?

Comment: @cigien No....I want to see if it has an "interesting" move constructor

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "interesting"? Do you mean it's not *trivial* e.g. `=default`ed?

Comment: @cigien Correct

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you plan on doing with this concept, but I added an answer below anyway.

Comment: What do you mean by "save off the move constructor"? How do you plan to use it? How do you plan to manage without, in case it's not "interesting"? Could you show a sketch of that "type erased class" you are trying to create? What's the purpose of that class? Your `NoMove` is in fact movable, meaning `NoMove src; NoMove dest = std::move(src);` compiles (or would, if you provide a default constructor), and would call the copy constructor.

Comment: @Igor Edited to provide a rough sketch of the type erased class

Comment: @DarthRubik: Why are you using `std::function` for something you could trivially just make a function pointer? Just have a static member template that does what you're doing. Also, your type has issues compared to `std::variant`; it heap allocates despite knowing exactly what types its going to store. Lastly, just because a move constructor is trivial doesn't mean you can choose not to call it. A trivial move constructor copies all of the subobjects of the type. That's something that still needs to be done.

Comment: @NicolBolas This is just a sketch of the use case....The actual implementation has the ability to switch between heap storage, stack storage, or some other custom allocator.  For the sake of brevity that isn't shown here.

Comment: @NicolBolas A trivial move constructor does nothing actually.....it doesn't move all sub objects.....But that isn't the point.....If the user doesn't define a move constructor, then I won't define a move constructor (read that as copies will be made instead of moving)

Comment: @DarthRubik: "*A trivial move constructor does nothing actually*" Do not make me look up the exact section in the C++ standard that shows this is false. Trivial move constructors do something. If a type is moveable and has any subobjects, its move constructor *does something*. `int` is moveable and it is trivially moveable. Are you saying that moving an `int` into another `int` does nothing?

Comment: @NicolBolas Sorry I didn't mean to say it didn't do anything....I meant to say it wasn't doing any memory managment or what ever else is going on if it is trivial (it is the moral equivalent of a memcpy if it is "trivial")

Comment: @DarthRubik: That's true. But you still need to invoke the move constructor even if it's trivial. `memcpy` is allowed to copy the bits of a live object to a live object, but it can't make the object become alive just by doing a copy.

Comment: You can't move `NoMove` with `memcpy` though, despite its lack of a user-defined move constructor. What is supposed to be the behavior of `type_eraser_thing<NoMove>`? The move constructor in particular. Shouldn't it get copied in there somewhere, and how do you plan to pull that off while not saving `move_constr`?

Comment: `move_constr` in your example doesn't make any sense. It attempts to call a constuctor taking `void*` parameter, which none of the classes in your example provide. Did you mean something like `return new (dest) T(std::move(*(T*)src));`?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik If the type doesn't define a move constructor then I won't either which means that when the user does a `std::move(thing)` it won't call the move constructor (cause there isn't one) it will call the copy constructor

Comment: @IgorTandetnik You are correct, I need some casts in there

Comment: In your example, the copy constructor for `type_eraser_thing` just copies `obj` pointer, so you end up with two objects owning the same pointer. Is that the way you want it? It's kinda weird to see a class where the move constructor does a deep copy, while the copy constructor does a shallow copy. Or are you saying you are going to have `copy_constr` similar to `move_constr`, and use that in the copy constructor?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik The two objects owning the same pointer is a bug......There will also be a copy_constr similar to the move constructor, which I omitted, but it will be there....

Comment: So what you want to detect is whether moving is equivalent to copying for a given type. In general, `type_eraser_thing` would store both `copy_constr` and `move_constr`; but if you could determine that the two are equivalent, then you could only store one. I'm afraid I can't think of a way to pull that off.

Comment: @Igor Well It should be as simple as is the move constructor defined....because in the struct: `struct A { A(A const&) {}};` there is no move constructor (not even a compiler provided one)

Answer (score 1):

The concept you seem to be looking for is:

```
template <typename T>
concept C = not std::is_trivially_move_constructible_v<T>;
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Wcx3K8).

If you don't have c++20, you can write this trait yourself, or just use the right hand side where needed, since it's pretty short.

Comment: You answered what you edited my question to be, but this doesn't help with the original question......Here is an example: https://godbolt.org/z/TPe66q